# Canvas not found in IE 11

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to use HTML canvas in my code. but when i fetch this canvas in my js file with the code

```
document.getElementById(id);
this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

it returns a **DispHTMLUnknownElement** which does not have **getContext** method. This works perfect in **Chrome** but gives issue in **IE 11**.

I am struggling with this issue for hours now. Please help

Regards

Comment: you will have to show a bit more of your code : some HTML markup, and a few more lines of your js, since currently, `document.getElementById(id);` is not related to `this.canvas`

Comment: Thx for your reply. I am using RGraph library. While debugging i found that it is not able to get the Canvas object using above line i.e. getElementByID. Below is the code

Comment: RGraph.Line = function (conf)
    {
        if (   typeof conf === 'object'
            && typeof conf.data === 'object'
            && typeof conf.id === 'string') {
            var id                        = conf.id;
            var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
            var data                      = conf.data;
            var parseConfObjectForOptions = true; 
               this.id                 = id;
        this.canvas             = canvas;
        this.context            = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

Comment: here id is the id of the canvas object specified in my HTML

Comment: Please include all this in an [edit] to your question then delete these comments.